# How to fix "The type 'ScriptRuntime' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced", when I use IronPython in Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, ironpython

I used IronPython in Unity3D to import a .py file by C#.

However, there is an error. I don't know why.

> "The type '`ScriptRuntime`' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced."

I don't know how to fix it.
Could you help me? Thank you very much!

C# code

```
//I used several package
using UnityEngine;
using IronPython.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Scripting;
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
```

And the error is at these following lines.

```
ScriptRuntime pyRunTime = Python.CreateRuntime();
dynamic obj = pyRunTime.UseFile("hello.py");
```

Comment: Is it also complaining about line `Python.CreateRuntime()` ?

Comment: Yes! Both `ScriptRuntime` and `Python.CreateRuntime()`.